# BBerry OS 5.x Titanium support

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

We would like to use Appcelerator Titanium to develop an IOS, Android and Blackberry OS 5.x app. I know IOS and Android are supported but is BBerry OS 5.x also supported as there's no mention of it in the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been various preview releases over the last several years of BlackBerry support in Titanium. They've all been withdrawn, except for the most recent one, BlackBerry 10. You could hunt around the internet and perhaps find an old copy of one of the old versions (it was only released temporarily to customers), but it wouldn't be "supported", as your question stipulates it must be.

BlackBerry 10 is the only one in preview availability. The source has been released, and you can read about it on their blog:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/12/announcing-preview-availability-of-the-blackberry-sdk.html

Comment: My question was not regarding BBerry 10 but BBerry 5/6/7.x (the legacy java sdk) support in Appcelerator.

Comment: Right. The others are not supported.

Comment: I found this link https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/BlackBerry+Support which seems to say that at least for ver 1.7x of Titanium, BBerry legacy was supported. Can I download that version of TI and follow those instructions? Or is that also obsolete?

Comment: You can grab 1.7.x off of the CI server still: go to http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html and change the drop down to 1_7_x.

Comment: I got confirmation from Appcelerator that there's no support for BBerry legacy OS. Archived versions of Appceletrator supported BB legacy only as beta for paying customers, it never was a released product.